# How does elasticsearch find the intersection of two search results like mysql?

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch

1. query name sets from 20151216 to 20151217

   ```
   {
   "from": 0,
   "size": 200,
   "query": {
       "bool": {
           "must": {
               "range": {
                   "DATE": {
                       "from": 20151216,
                       "to": 2015121617,
                       "include_lower": true,
                       "include_upper": true
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   },
   "_source": {
       "includes": [
           "NAME"
       ],
       "excludes": []
   }
   ```

   }
2. Another day

   ```
    {
   "from": 0,
   "size": 200,
   "query": {
       "bool": {
           "must": {
               "range": {
                   "DATE": {
                       "from": 20151217,
                       "to": 2015121618,
                       "include_lower": true,
                       "include_upper": true
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   },
   "_source": {
       "includes": [
           "NAME"
       ],
       "excludes": []
   }
   ```

   }

If in MYSQL I will use the following SQL to solve my problem.

```
SELECT NAME FROM Table1 where DATE between 20151216 and 20151217 intersect SELECT NAME FROM Table1 where DATE between 20151217 and 20151218
```

How does elasticsearch to find the intersection of two search results like mysql?

Comment: Why u cant use just something like http://pastebin.com/phpDsuLn ?

Comment: like this?SELECT NAME FROM Table1 where DATE between 20151216 and 20151217 and DATE between 20151217 and 20151218, Meaningless！！！And also no results.